# Vb.net How could I hide mp3 files in a external file (.bin or other?) and then get this file [ opening with AxWMP ]

Tags: vb.net, mp3

Simply I just want to make it harder to get the mp3 files of the program. Can they be contained in 1 directory that will be harder to access? I don't want it be attached into the program to avoid large .exe file better are some external files /songs.(extension?) .

If its possible tell me 
->How could I compress this files in 1 directory(extension) and how to get this file later via vb to play it via vb

How I get a file into the player.

```
AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = mediaList(ListBox1.SelectedIndex)
```

mediaList what it does.

```
Dim mediaList As New List(Of String)

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    OpenFileDialog1.Multiselect = True
    OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
    For Each s As String In OpenFileDialog1.FileNames
        mediaList.Add(s)
        ListBox1.Items.Add(System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(s))
    Next
    Me.ListBox1.SelectedIndex = Me.ListBox1.SelectedIndex + 1

End Sub
```

Please give me some hints

Answer (score 0):

You could probably just add a few dummy bytes to the beginning of the file so they aren't recognized as MP3.  Then, when you go to play your "altered" MP3 files, take those dummy bytes out and play the "original" file.

Comment: Sounds nice but how to do something like that?

Comment: Just have no idea how to do it. Googled it up but no results for mp3 files. And how to decode it seems legitly hard